# How does the system know which paths to search for executables?

Tags: command-line

I know there are directories like `/bin`, `/sbin`, `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin` and so on, and that files in those directories can be run directly from the terminal. How does the terminal know to look at those paths?

I've heard that the paths are stored in `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `~/.bashrc`, but `/sbin` is not present in those files. Is there a specific file in which the paths are set, and can we add our own paths, other than using bashrc?

Comment: Look at the output of `echo $PATH`. Then look inside of `/etc/environment` file. Maybe you will make an idea.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu PATH = (/etc/environment + bashrc)'s containments ? is it true?

Comment: First time the value for PATH is assigned in `/etc/environment` file, then its value can be changed in any [shell initialization files](http://linux.die.net/Bash-Beginners-Guide/sect_03_01.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/environment` contains all data about path of that programs you can add new path there.

Path included in `/etc/environment`, `/etc/bash.bashrc` , `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` is automatically initialized after loging into shell.

Comment: terminal look at /etc/environment or bashrc?

Comment: +1 ... but.. still again, terminal look at /etc/environment or bashrc? which one ? both of them ? If yes how? By profile?

Answer (score 0):

Yes PATH variable.  You can create your own bin directory as follows:
    `mkdir $HOME/bin`
Add $HOME/bin to the PATH variable using bash shell export command:
    `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin`
    `echo $PATH`
Move hello.sh in $HOME/bin using the mv command, run:
    `mv hello.sh $HOME/bin`
Execute the script at any path:
    `hello.sh`

Comment: when you type "export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin" this path save in where?

Comment: Saved in PATH, the variable.   PATH is a variable name, bash.bashrc is a file(a script) that configured some behavior of bash, these behavior might need to use the variable PATH. PATH is the basics.

Comment: On Ubuntu, there is no need to add `~/bin` to $PATH, it already is included by default.

Answer (score 0):

The paths for executable scripts and files are in the PATH environment variable:

```
env | grep PATH
```